# How Can I fix it?The app shows error in API key just like (KeyError: 'Api Key not found. ')

Tags: python, django, airtable

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib import messages
from airtable import Airtable
import os


AT = Airtable(os.environ.get('AIRTABLE_MOVIESTABLE_BASE_ID'),
             'Movies',
             api_key=os.environ.get('AIRTABLE_API_KEY'))

# Create your views here.
def home_page(request):
    ##print(str(request.GET.get('query','')))
    user_query=str(request.GET.get('query',''))

    return render(request,'movies/movies_stuff.html')
```

Comment: Please provide the entire error message. Have you done any debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Well from the look of it you are trying to retrieve data from an API endpoint in which the authentication fails hence you can't retrieve data, Try to check if you have pip installed the package correctly or you can try to run

```html
pip install "djangorestframework-api-key==2.*"
```

and defined it under installed apps in the settings.

```html
# settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
  # ...
  "rest_framework",
  "rest_framework_api_key",
]
```